# How to get the last message of a specific channel discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get the last message of a specific channel but I've couldn't do that, I want that if i write a command in another channel (Channel 1) that command gives me the last message of another channel (channel 2).

My code is:

```
client.on('message', (message)=>{
    if(message.channel.id === '613553889433747477'){
        if(message.content.startsWith('start')){

                message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
                    let lastMessage = messages.first();
                    console.log(lastMessage.content);
                  })
                  .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: `message.channel.id` is the id of channel 2?

Comment: Yes it is. It's the id of the channel 2

Comment: So its show any error or just stuck?  Its passing all your if statements ?

Comment: I'm stuck, in the console it doesn't show me any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up you code a bit, and added some comments explaining what is happening.
If you have more questions, i would recommend visiting the official Discord.js Discord server.
https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9

```js
client.on('message', message => {

  // Check if the message was sent in the channel with the specified id.
  // NOTE, this defines the message variable that is going to be used later.
  if(message.channel.id === '613553889433747477'){
    if(message.content.startsWith('start')) {

      // Becuase the message varibable still refers to the command message,
      // this method will fetch the last message sent in the same channel as the command message.
      message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
        const lastMessage = messages.first()
        console.log(lastMessage.content)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to get a message from another channel, you can do something like this.
And use the command `start #channel`

```js
client.on('message', message => {

  // Check if the message was sent in the channel with the specified id.
  if(message.channel.id === '613553889433747477'){
    if(message.content.startsWith('start')) {

      // Get the channel to fetch the message from.
      const channelToCheck = message.mentions.channels.first()

      // Fetch the last message from the mentioned channel.
      channelToCheck.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
        const lastMessage = messages.first()
        console.log(lastMessage.content)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

More about mentioning channels in messages can be found here. 
 https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions

Comment: Sorry but, in the code you gave me, where can i add the Id of the channel #2??, If i put your code i get an error "Cannot read property 'fetchMessages' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry for being late to answer, but if you want to specify the channel by id, change this line  
`const channelToCheck = message.mentions.channels.first()` to  
`const channelToCheck = message.guild.channels.get('ID_OF_CHANNEL')`